# How to get string value when used data-name in JQuery in MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to get name string from data-rName into JQuery. Currently, it is showing undefined. This `rName`  should  returns Name string but not value.

View

```
  <tr id="row" data-rName="@dr["rName"]" >
```

Script

```
  $('#DetailsPartial').on('click', '#row', function () {                  
           var rName = $(this).data('rName');           
        });
```

Comment: What is `$(this)` in this context ? Is it the jQuery object for the row ?

Comment: Inspect the html you are generating - what does `@dr["rName"]` generate?

Comment: @Shyju, i updated Jquery portion.

Comment: @it is showing `undefined` now. This is string value coming from database.

Comment: And your `<tr>` element does not have a `id="row"` attribute. You need to show us the code to reproduce your issue. What is the element with `id="row"`? (and it also suggests you have duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Yes I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html5 data attribute name should not contain upper case letters.

Here is the relevant part from the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).

> A custom data attribute is an attribute in no namespace whose name
>   starts with the string "data-", has at least one character after the
>   hyphen, is XML-compatible, and contains no uppercase ASCII letters.

So change your attribute name to all lower case

```
<tr data-rname="some value" id="row"><td></td></tr>
```

and

```
$('#DetailsPartial').on('click', '#row', function () {                  
    var rName = $(this).data('rname'); 
    alert(rName);          
});
```

You may also use dash in the attribute name. For example,

and

```
var rName = $("#hello").data("r-name");
```

Comment: Solved!. Thank you alot.